# jQuery within "Load" problem

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting jQuery to load inside a file that has been imported using jQuery **load**.

Here is the code I'm using to get the external page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeLinks a").click(function() {
            $("#changeMe").fadeIn("slow").load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Aimed at a simple div (#changeMe).

I've heard about possibly using "**live**" but I don't have any experience with that function so I'm confused.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Delegate instead.  It's faster than just a normal `live` call as it has a context.  This means that events won't need to bubble up to the top document level.  You can accomplish the same with `live` as of jQuery 1.4, but I prefer `delegate`'s syntax.

```
$('#changeLinks').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    //click event
});
```

That having been said, I find your provided sample a bit weird.  Is your click handler loading in dynamic data that should also fire that same click handler?

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you very much. I'll mark it in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeLinks a").live('click', function() {
        $("#changeMe").fadeIn("slow").load(this.href); //DOM href property
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: @Alexwhine, is the function there on page load?